# finding number of weekdays between 2 dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an object which has got an attribute called effective_date which of Date type. 
I have to a task 3 weekdays before a objects effective_date from today.
Example: If effective_date is Sat, 29 Sep 2012 i have to do a task on Tue, 25th Sep 2012. i.e 3 weekdays before sat. . 
If effective_date is Sun, 30 Sep 2012 i have to do a task on Wed, 26th Sep 2012. i.e 3 weekdays before sat. 
If effective_date is Fri, 28 Sep 2012 i have to do a task on Tue, 25th Sep 2012. i.e 3 weekdays before sat. (wed, thur, fri) 
I tried some code but it does not work for all cases. Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the [Weekdays gem](https://github.com/mdarby/weekdays). It allows you to do stuff like

```
>> -3.weekdays_from(Date.civil(2012,9,28))
=> Tue, 25 Sep 2012
>> -3.weekdays_from(Date.civil(2012,9,29))
=> Wed, 26 Sep 2012
>> -3.weekdays_from(Date.civil(2012,9,30))
=> Wed, 26 Sep 2012
```

or perhaps the [business_time gem](https://github.com/bokmann/business_time) that does the same thing with a different syntax:

```
>> 3.business_days.before(Date.civil(2012,9,28))
=> 2012-09-25 00:00:00 +0200
>> 3.business_days.before(Date.civil(2012,9,29))
=> 2012-09-26 00:00:00 +0200
>> 3.business_days.before(Date.civil(2012,9,30))
=> 2012-09-26 00:00:00 +0200
```

Comment: Thanks a lot i'll look into. Wonder how the gem is doing it though.

Comment: Read the code in the gem: https://github.com/mdarby/weekdays/blob/master/lib/weekdays.rb   `until x == self;
            curr_date -= 1.days;
            x -= 1 if curr_date.weekday?;
          end`

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate over the days, counting as you go, for example to count the number of week days between the  26th of september and the 30th you could do

```
(Date::civil(2012,9,26)..Date::civil(2012,9,30)).count {|date| date.wday >= 1 && date.wday <= 5}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading what the gems do, you can also do your own helper method:

```
require 'active_support/core'

module Weekdays
  WD_AGO_DIFF = Hash.new(1).merge(1=>3, 0=>2)
  WD_FROM_DIFF = Hash.new(1).merge(5=>3, 6=>2)
  def weekdays_before(date=Time.now)
    self.times.inject(date) { |d| d - WD_AGO_DIFF[d.wday].days }
  end
  def weekdays_after(date=Time.now)
    self.times.inject(date) { |d| d + WD_FROM_DIFF[d.wday].days }
  end
end

class Fixnum
  include Weekdays
end

6.times do |n|
  p [n, n.weekdays_before, n.weekdays_after]
end
```